# Use the result of a shell command in a conditional in a makefile

Tags: shell, makefile, sh

I am trying to execute a command in a conditional in a makefile.

I got it working in a shell:

```
if [ -z "$(ls -A mydir)" ]; then \
  echo "empty dir"; \
else \
  echo "non-empty dir"; \
fi
```

but if I try it in a makefile, `"$(ls -A mydir)"` expands to nothing whatever if `asdf` is empty or not:

```
all:
    if [ -z "$(ls -A mydir)" ]; then \
      echo "empty dir"; \
    else \
      echo "non-empty dir"; \
    fi
```

The `ls` command does not expand as I expect:

```
$ mkdir mydir
$ make
if [ -z "" ]; then \
      echo "empty dir"; \
    else \
      echo "non-empty dir"; \
    fi
empty dir
$ touch mydir/myfile
$ make
if [ -z "" ]; then \
      echo "empty dir"; \
    else \
      echo "non-empty dir"; \
    fi
empty dir
$ ls -A mydir
myfile
```

How do I make the command work inside the conditional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have little experience in writing makefiles. However I think you must use two dollar signs in your recipe:

```
all:
    if [ -z "$$(ls -A mydir)" ]; then \
```

[https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Variables-in-Recipes:](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Variables-in-Recipes)

> if you want a dollar sign to appear in your recipe, you must double
>   it (‘$$’).

This is an example of output after I changed your makefile and added `$$(ls -A mydir)`:

```
$ ls mydir/
1

$ make
if [ -z "$(ls -A mydir)" ]; then \
      echo "empty dir"; \
    else \
      echo "non-empty dir"; \
    fi
non-empty dir

$ rm mydir/1

$ make
if [ -z "$(ls -A mydir)" ]; then \
      echo "empty dir"; \
    else \
      echo "non-empty dir"; \
    fi
empty dir
```

Comment: When I see it, it's so obvious I am ashamed I even had to ask. Thanks.