# Ampersand separated commands in a Makefile

Tags: python, makefile, virtualenv, python-venv

I have the following rule on my Makefile.

```
init-local-env:
    @echo 'initializing python3 local environment in .venv'
    python3 -m venv .venv && source .venv/bin/activate
```

But does not take me to my virtual environment. It seems, only the first part of the command is run by the Makefile, because it had created the `.venv` folder, and only after I run `source .venv/bin/activate` on the terminal, it takes me to the environment.

But, if I run these two commands on the terminal, it runs without an issue, and it takes me to the environment as well.

```
python3 -m venv .venv && source .venv/bin/activate
```

I tried to use an `if` clause by referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28090490/use-the-result-of-a-shell-command-in-a-conditional-in-a-makefile).

```
init-local-env:
    @echo 'initializing python3 local environment in .venv'
    if [ -z "$$(python3 -m venv .venv)" ]; then \
        source .venv/bin/activate; \
    fi
```

But it doesn't seem to work either. It gives me the below output and creates the `.venv` folder, but does not execute the second command.

```
bash$ make init-local-env
initializing python3 local environment in .venv
if [ -z "$(python3 -m venv .venv)" ]; then \
        source .venv/bin/activate; \
    fi
```

Any idea, what I'm doing wrong?
And how can I run these two commands one after the other ( using && ) ?

Comment: I am not familiar with the python virtual env functionality, but could it be that you expect the make process to change the process from which you are invoking make? That's not possible, `source .venv/bin/activate` lives in a subprocess with no permission to influence your current terminal session.

Comment: @lubgr : Makes sense. But isn't there any other way that I can accomplish this?

Comment: If it's only about making things convenient, consider a bash alias? This doesn't suffer from the limitiations a subprocess has, because it's simply pasted into your terminal and then interpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line of a makefile rule is executed by a separate shell. Hence, after `source .venv/bin/activate` executed it terminates that shell and starts a new one on the next line without the effects of `source .venv/bin/activate`.

You can make GNU make execute all lines in one shell, see [Using One Shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html).